# How do I put a msmysql DB backup onto mySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to move a msmysql database onto a webhost mySQL? I'm working with this tutorial for a private Dekaron server and its saying to use msmysql 2000. However I already have a webhost that allows me upto 40 and uses mySQL. Is there anyway to put these database backups onto the mySQL instead?

Comment: Waht is msmysql DB?

Comment: its something from microsoft, I have the direct download link from the tutorial I was following. I can't seem to find it via google but the download is from microsoft. My server runs on ubuntu so I'm unable to use this and am really REALLY hoping for using mySQL instead http://download.microsoft.com/download/SQLSVR2000/Trial/2000/NT45/EN-US/SQLEVAL.exe

Comment: There is no such thing as `msmysql`. It's called `MsSQL`. The link you've posted is about `SQL Server 2000`. These three are completely distinct.

Comment: is there a way to have the databases function on a mySQL server tho?

Comment: I don't understand your question, so you need to be a clear about that. Step by step, what do you need?

Comment: so, I have a database backup that is meant for some sql server program that is made by microsoft. however my webhost is using mySQL.

I need to know how to convert this database to where it would instead be on mySQL